# git diff of copies that only added lines

Tags: git, diff

Say I have two processes that **append lines** to copies of the same original (parent) file (`copy_A` and `copy_B`). If I `diff` these copies, can `diff` ever conclude that we have a conflict? (i.e. can it ever conclude that `copy_A` and `copy_B` made edits to the **same line**)?

Note that none of the processes remove lines, they both **add** lines, but I wonder if `diff` (specifically `git`) could ever conclude that they were editing the same line (as opposed to concluding that they both **added different lines**)

In my case specifically, I am working with `csv` files (both processes append records to their own copies of a `csv` file, i.e. the original `csv` file being the same at the beginning), and I am hoping to **git merge** these csv files hopefully automatically without conflicts. Can I make that assumption?

#### Update:

Assuming that both processes are **appending** lines to the same file on their own branches that we hope to merge onto master at some point. Is there any way to tell git (diff) that they both correspond to additions to have it automatically merge the changes (adding entries perhaps in block, e.g. all of A's additions followed by B's additions)

Comment: If you "diff copy_A copy_B", every line after the initial stretch of identical lines will be a conflict.  How could it be otherwise?

Comment: "two processes that append lines" "made edits to the same line". Which is it? Lines are only appended, or the same line is edited?

Comment: @KyleJones There are times when two people add code to the same file independently and `git merge` concludes that the changes can be automatically merged without conflict. This only happens when diff concludes that they were editing different lines.

Comment: @Patrick lines are only **appended**, but can `diff` ever conclude otherwise? That's the question.

Comment: You mean such as this?: `diff -u <(echo -e 'foo\nhello there\nbar') <(echo -e 'foo\nhello world\nbar')`

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Yes. I guess the output of that diff answers the question? Is there any way to set things up (diff or git) to have it conclude that it is safe to automatically merge because they were not editing the same line? (will update OP)

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom merge driver as explained in [strategy for git and append-mostly files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841127/strategy-for-git-and-append-mostly-files).

This way you can specify that the way to merge files is to append them, rather than to stop and ask the user to resolve the conflict that is trivially solved by appending.